# DEVISE - No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Nothing on the internet solved this problem.

I'm running on Rails 4.2.3 and Ruby 2.1.5
After an installation of devise, I got this error.

When I delete the line 
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %` from my layout file, the error is gone and everyting looks fine.

I tried everything found on stackoverflow, didn't work.

Right now:

- I use `<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>` in my layout.
- I tried to change the initializer : `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to "get" also, didn't work. Now remains "delete". Anyway it should be delete in my opinion.
- My application.js file includes : `//= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require turbolinks
  //= require_tree .`
- Routes.rb file includes `devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}`. If I don't add this line, it's not working also.

If I delete `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %` from my layout file it's working. If I don't, it's not working.

What is the problem with this javascript thing? Any opinion is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried just disabling/uninstalling turbolinks from your app?

Comment: Yes I did. The error is gone only if I delete all the "javascript_include_tag 'application'," line from the layout. The interesting thing is, there was no problem when I developed an other application with the same way a couple weeks ago. @jakub-bilko

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquery-turbolinks gem and modify your application.js to look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: Do you have any other files in your app/assets/javascripts/ folder? Or any code in you application.js? When your page loads, there is any error or warning in the JS console of your browser?

Comment: No there is nothing else. In fact, when I create a new rails application with scaffolding just to test if that'd be working, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem seems like because of Windows. The solution is adding the gemfile : `'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` and `bundle update coffee-script-source` This solved.